# weird interface of qgis 3.2.2

Tags: qgis

I recently installed the 3.2.2 version of QGIS but the interface seems to be weird

[image]

How can  make the map canevas occupy the rest of the window?

Comment: @HeikkiVesanto it's a bug on mac. they say to install the last released version of QGIS and it's what I have now. Anyway thank you I will just reinstall an older version and see if it does behave the same way

Comment: They say to install an older version, or wait for a new version. The bug is in 3.2.2.